# MDFS Warning Message

Tags: r

"In ComputePValue(MIG.Result$IG, dimensions = dimensions, divisions = divisions,  :
  Poor goodness of fit for the distribution"

Obtaining the above warning message when running the MDFS function in the MDFS package, such as:

```
d1 <- MDFS(x, y, n.contrast = 0, dimensions = 1, divisions = 1, range = 0)
```

where x is the variables to test significance and y is a binary response variable.  A few notes on the dataset:

- 34 input variables (x)
- input variables all numeric
- 13345 rows of data